# Help me identify this kanji on my knife box

Tags: kanji, readings, handwriting, calligraphy

For context, it's a nakiri made by artist 藤原兼房. The blade is a 50/50 grind, so it's not left or right handed.

[image]

I can read every character except the third one down on the left.

Reading from the right:

> 日本鋼鍛錬　高級◯料理庖丁
>   にほんこうたんれん　こうきゅう◯りょうりほうちょう
>   Japanese forged steel high quality ?? kitchen knife.

The best I could figure was it was 乃 or 右 but drawn weird. All the others look ok although the 高 looks like it's drawn in the old style.  So maybe it's an archaic character.

Answer (score 6):

It's 御 (generic honorable prefix) written in cursive style.

See picture here: http://www.fan.hi-ho.ne.jp/chikusui/newpage18.htm